# Third Normal Form (3NF) Decomposition Scenario

Tags: database-design, normalization, relational-theory

I am trying to understand what are the steps to check if a decomposition of table is in 3NF.

There is a specific exercise I'm trying to solve with no success.

- Given that `R={A1,A2,A3,A4}`
- and `F={A1→A2A3A4,A2→A3,A3→A4,A4→A2}`

The decomposition is:

- `R1={A1,A4}`
- `R2={A4,A2}, A3={A2,A3}`

(super keys are shown in bold)

According to the answers this decomposition is not in 3NF.

Unfortunately, I cant understand why. My main difficulty is the transitivity check, and a couple of questions have arisen:

1. Should I check transitivity per table?
2. While doing that should I ignore every dependency in *a*→*b* in *F* if *a* or *b* does not exist in the table?